# Google Chrome - Can't load local images with HTML?

Tags: html, css

is it possible to load an image locally on the google chrome console? I tried but it obviously doesn't work ??

```
<img src="img/photo.jpg" alt="picture" width="300" height="300">
```

Do have you an idea please?

Comment: It is possible, but you have to make sure the path is correct. In this case, if your html file sits in `/foo` folder, browser will attempt to load the image from `/foo/img/photo.jpg` path - unless `<base>` element has overridden the base path.

Comment: In this case your image will be displayed only if img and your html file are in same folder otherwise add full address of image.

Comment: I want to add an image via google chrome console, the site is not mine. I don't have the source code

Comment: You cannot reference a local file from the HTML of a file served from a different domain. That would open all kinds of security holes.

Answer (score 0):

As much I know, you can't because the website is fetching the from the server, not from your local drive. If you try to open the image file you will get domain.extention/path/image-name

So I think you can't do it

Answer (score -1):

You need put your code in html.file to see the image, in browser you just can see the DOM https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

Comment: The DOOM? It's not that bad! It's just DOM :).